# EFCore PostgreSQL: Ошибка ограничения первичного ключа

Tags: c#, postgresql, ef-core-3.1

**Я использую:**

1. PostgreSQL 13.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit;
2. Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Version=3.1.4.0

**Модели:**

```cs
public class BaseModel
 {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
 }

public class UserModel : BaseModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(ModelValidationConstants.User.LOGIN_STRING_LENGTH)]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        [StringLength(ModelValidationConstants.User.PASSWORD_STRING_LENGTH)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [StringLength(ModelValidationConstants.User.PASSWORD_SALT_STRING_LENGTH)]
        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public UserOriginEntity UserOrigin { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

**Конфигурация модели:**

```cs
public class UserModelConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserModel>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserModel> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("user");

            builder.HasIndex(entity => entity.Login)
               .IsUnique(false);

            builder.HasIndex(entity => new { entity.Login, entity.Password })
                 .IsUnique(true);

            builder.HasIndex(entity => new { entity.Login, entity.UserOrigin })
                .IsUnique(true);
        }
    }
```

**После добавления миграций и обновления БД, получилась следующая таблица:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE tsdb."user"
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    login character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    passwordsalt character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    userorigin integer NOT NULL,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

**Когда выполняется следующий код:**

```cs
           using(var context = new PostgreContext())
            {
                if (context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == TEST_USER_LOGIN) != null)
                    return;

                context.Users.Add(new UserModel()
                {
                    Login = TEST_USER_LOGIN,
                    Password = "TestPassword",
                    PasswordSalt = "TestPasswordSalt",
                    UserOrigin = Entities.Enums.UserOriginEntity.InternalSystem
                });

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Я получаю exception: PostgresException: 23505: : повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "pk_user".
Такое поведение наблюдается на "свежей" БД. Так же в БД вставлены начальные данные, в частности пользователь-админ.
Не могу понять что не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> в БД вставлены начальные данные

вставлены как? Ну, я и так знаю, что `id` вы сами при этом какие-то выбрали и использовали. В частности, использовали 1 вместо механизма `IDENTITY`, что особенно важно, объявленного именно как `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`.

```
melkij=> create temp table foo (
  id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
     INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1
  ) , val int);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> insert into foo (id, val) values(1,1);
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> insert into foo (val) values(2);
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> table foo;
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 |   1
  1 |   2
(2 строки)
```

Иначе говоря - а кто будет сообщать этому `sequence` о том, что какие-то значения вы присвоили самостоятельно? Никто. Вы (вернее ваш фреймворк) попросили `BY DEFAULT`, именно это поведение и получили, новое значение последовательности генерируется только если при добавлении строки не было указано явное значение.

Вам нужно изменить значение следующего генерируемого значения:

```
select max(id)+1 from tsdb."user";
ALTER TABLE tsdb."user" ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH /* результат предыдущего запроса */;
```

---

Если бы вы попросили `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` - то получили бы любезную ошибку при попытке делать странное:

```
melkij=> create temp table foo (id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED always AS IDENTITY ( 
    INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1) , val int);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> insert into foo (id, val) values(1,1);
ERROR:  cannot insert into column "id"
ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
ПОДСКАЗКА:  Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
```

А `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` и должен себя ввести так как ведёт.

Comment: спасибо большое за Ваш развернутый ответ. Обязательно попробую изменить способ генерации IDENTITY. По результатам отпишусь комментарием.

Comment: @melkij, кстати, после нескольких ошибочных попыток вставить запись в БД, записи начинают вставляться без ошибок.

Comment: Да, само собой. Sequence намеренно не транзакционен. Даже если запрос завершился ошибкой, значение счётчика уже увеличилось.

Comment: @melkij, причина проблемы, которую Вы описали кроется в фреймворке npgSql EF Core, который не реагирует на сидирование данных и не инкрементит Sequence. Решение данной проблемы рассматривается тут:https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/367. Предлагается два пути решения: 1. Для сидирования данных использовать отрицательные идентификаторы; 2. Либо воспользоватся .HasIdentityOptions(startValue:<требуемое начальное значение>), где "требуемое начальное значение" равно "количество сидируемых данных"+1;

Answer (score 0):

Решение данной проблемы рассматривается тут:[github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/367](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/367). Предлагается два пути решения:

1. Для сидирования данных использовать отрицательные идентификаторы, например:

```cs
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>().HasData(new UserModel[]
            {
                new UserModel()
                {
                    Id = -1,
                    Login = "admin",
                    PasswordSalt = "admin salt",
                    Password = "admin password",
                }
            });
```

2. Либо воспользоватся .HasIdentityOptions(startValue:<требуемое начальное значение>), где "требуемое начальное значение" равно "количество сидируемых данных"+1, например:

```cs
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>().Property(u => u.Id)
                                 .UseIdentityAlwaysColumn()
                                 .HasIdentityOptions(startValue:2);
```